# how to generate a table of random data from existing database table through oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, random, procedure

I have to generate a table (contains two columns) of random data from a database table through oracle procedure. The user can indicate the number of data required and we have to use the table data with ID values from 1001 to 1060. I am trying to use cursor loop and not sure dbms_random method dhould I use.

I am using the following code to create procedure

```
create or replace procedure a05_random_plant(p_count in number)
as
v_count number := p_count;
cursor c is 
select plant_id, common_name
from ppl_plants
where rownum = v_count
order by dbms_random.value;
begin
delete from a05_random_plants_table;
for c_table in c
loop
insert into a05_random_plants_table(plant_id, plant_name)
                        values (c_table.plant_id, c_table.common_name);
end loop;
end;
/
```

it complied successfully. Then I executed with the following code

```
set serveroutput on
exec a05_random_plant(5);
```

it shows anonymous block completed
but when run the following code, I do not get any records

```
select * from a05_random_plants_table;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rownum=value would not work for a value greater than 1

hence try the below

```
        create or replace procedure a05_random_plant(p_count in number)
        as
        v_count number := p_count;
        cursor c is 
        select plant_id, common_name
        from ppl_plants
        where rownum <= v_count
        order by dbms_random.value;
        begin
        delete from a05_random_plants_table;
        for c_table in c
        loop
        insert into a05_random_plants_table(plant_id, plant_name)
                                values (c_table.plant_id, c_table.common_name);
        end loop;
        end;
        /
```

Answer (score 0):

Query by Tom Kyte - will generate almost 75K of rows:

```
select trunc(sysdate,'year')+mod(rownum,365) TRANS_DATE,
       mod(rownum,100) CUST_ID,
       abs(dbms_random.random)/100 SALES_AMOUNT
 from all_objects
/
```

You can use this example to write your query and add where clause to it - where id between 1001 and 1060, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use a cursor (which is slow naturally) but do a direct insert from a select:

```
insert into table (col1, col2)
select colx, coly from other_table...
```

And, isn't missing a COMMIT on the end of your procedure?

So, all code in your procedure would be a DELETE, a INSERT WITH that SELECT and then a COMMIT.